# Pattern Program Double Triangle in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's my code :

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    for j in range(1, i + 1):
        print('*', end=' ')
    print()

for i in range (n):
    for j in range (i+1):
        print('*', end=' ') 
    print()
```

and here's the output if I input 3:

```
* * * 
* *
*
*
* *
* * *
```

but I want to make it like this :

```
* * * 
* *
*
* *
* * *
```

Any solutions?

And how about '*' change into a number like this (depends on the input):

```
123
12
1
12
123
```

Comment: Seems like you have to remove either the last iteration from your first, or the first iteration from your second loop. Change the `range` accordingly.

Comment: Nice thank you, I change the first iteration in my first loop to `range(n, 1, -1)`

Answer (score 0):

Cleverish solution using list:

```
n = int(input())
l = ['* '*x for x in range(1,n+1)]
print(*reversed(l),sep="\n")
print(*l[1:],sep="\n")
```

Test case, for input 5:

```
* * * * *
* * * *
* * *
* *
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
```